# calculate max drawdown by year in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a stock series with closing prices. I want to calculate the max drawdown, but per year.

```
Date
1995-12-11     1.204
1995-12-12     1.184
1995-12-13     1.196
1995-12-14     1.192
1995-12-15     1.099
1995-12-18     1.005
...
2018-12-18     22.005
```

I use this to calculate the MDD:

```
drawdown =   close / close.cummax()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to calculate the cumulative maximum using something like `df.groupby('year').close.transform('cummax')`, provided that you have the `year` column. That creates a series of the same length as the other columns in the dataframe so you can easily divide the closing price by it.

In case you only have the date as a string and the closing price in a column called `close`, you can do:

```
df\
    .assign(year = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.date).dt.year)\
    .assign(close_cummax = lambda x: x.groupby('year').close.transform('cummax'))\
    .assign(mdd = lambda x: x.close/x.close_cummax)
```

I'm using chained methods above but if you don't like your code littered with lambda functions you can have individual statements for each change:

```
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.year
df['mdd'] = df.close / df.groupby('year').close.transform('cummax')
```